# Multi part download with libcurl

Tags: c++, download, libcurl, multipart

I want to be able break up a file and download it in parts. From what I've read I should be able to accomplish this with curlopt_range in libcurl. Unfortunately all example code I've seen is for php which I know nothing about. My question or questions are 1. Is downloading a file in parts with libcurl possible 2. How would I go about saveing the two separate parts because I assume I would have to the combine them after they have downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to specify which parts of remote resources to download with the use of the [curl_easy_setopt](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html)'s [CURLOPT_RANGE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTRANGE) option. You would simply do two (or more) downloads, each downloading its own separate part. When they finish, you merge the individual parts into a single complete one.